# ML approach for quantifying building quality perception

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-classification

I'm working on a project to model public perceptions of buildings in a tourism context, focusing on attributes like beauty and mystery. The data I have is a labeled dataset of building photos, each rated on a scale of 1 to 5 for these and a few other qualities.

Is there an approach for modeling the data, and even better, one that can account for varied perceptions?